# division between rows in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a new column in my matrix that is the rate of change from one point in time to the next. Using the the following matrix, this is a 3 step process.

```
n <- 20
data <- matrix(rnorm(2 * n), nrow = n)
```

1) Focusing on column 1, I want to divide row 2 by row 1.

2) I want to create a new column to hold the answer in row 2

3) repeat this process down the rows (3/2, 4/3,6/5, etc.)

I'm assuming a simple function like the following would be involved in step 1

```
y<-data[1,1]
z<-data[2,1]
roc<- function(x){(z/y)}
```

Step 2 is simple

```
data$ROC[data[1,] >= 0]<- roc
```

But I'm at a loss for step 3, and I'm not 100% sure that the function is correctly written.

Comment: I'm going to have to edit out the question about examples for other platforms (by which I think you meant languages) because of this: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: by that I meant there are examples out there for other languages (I guess), like SAS and MatLab, but I couldn't find one for R. Just trying to demonstrate that I did do some background research. Either way, I'm okay with removing it. Not looking for books, just help with the problem as described

Comment: The new column you want is `data[,1] / data.table::shift(data[,1])`

Comment: or `data[,1] / c(NA, head(data[,1], -1))`

Answer (score 0):

Complete answer based off Ryan's comment.

```
####data matrix####
n <- 20
data <- matrix(rnorm(2 * n), nrow = n)

####math####
y<-data[,1]/data.table::shift(data[,1])

####new column####
data$ROC[data[1,] >= 0]<- y
```